# Relationship between parent and child object

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a small app using PHP OOP and am struggling a little with how a child object relates or is part of the parent object.

I have a Team object and have a Player object that extends Team. I have a few Team objects and many Player Objects, I would like the player objects to be part of specific team objects. E.g.:

I guess what I'm struggling with is a high-level understanding of how I should approach this. Example of what I want:

- I instantiate the Team class with an Object called 'Brazil'
- I instantiate the Player class several times with Objects called 'Player one, Player two'
- I would like my app to understand that the Player one object is a child of the Brazil object
- I would then, for example, like to list all the players that are part of the Brazil object when I select Brazil in a form etc

At the moment I am not storing anything in a DB, just code. My code is actually really messy at this point and I don't feel it would help

```php
class Team {

    private $TeamName;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->TeamName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $TeamName
     */
    public function setTeamName($TeamName)
    {
        $this->TeamName = $TeamName;
    }

}


class Player extends Team
{

    private $playerName;

    private $position;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $playerName
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        parent::getTeamName();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $TeamName
     */
    public function setTeamName($TeamName)
    {
        parent::setTeamName($TeamName);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, a player is **not** a team, however a player **has** a Team. So It is not correct to make a player inherits Team, but to have a team property in the Player class.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. So basically I shouldn't be extending the Team class. Having a team property in player, does this in effect make the Team class redundant?

Comment: *"So basically I shouldn't be extending the Team class"*... Yes.  *"does this in effect make the Team class redundant"*... no, you create new team object and share it (the same team object) between all the players objects of the same team, I will give you an example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A player is **not** a Team, so it doesn't make sense to make it inherit Team, you should have a team as property of a player, here I adjusted your code to what I think is right

```
<?php
class Team {

    private $TeamName;

    protected $players = [];

    public function __construct($teamName)
    {
        $this->setTeamName($teamName);
    }


    public function addPlayer(Player $player)
    {
        $this->players[] = $player;
        $player->setPlayerTeam($this);
    }

    public function getAllPlayers()
    {
        return $this->players;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $TeamName
     */
    public function setTeamName($TeamName)
    {
        $this->TeamName = $TeamName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->TeamName;
    }

}



class Player
{

    private $playerName;

    private $position;

    protected $team;

    public function __construct($playerName, $position)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    public function setPlayerTeam(Team $team)
    {
        $this->team = $team;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->team->getTeamName();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $playerName
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }




}
```

testing the clasess

```
$brazil = new Team("Brazil");
$player1 = new Player("player1", "defender");
$player2 = new Player("player2", "attacker");

$brazil->addPlayer($player1);
$brazil->addPlayer($player2);

$brazilPlayers = $brazil->getAllPlayers();
foreach ($brazilPlayers as $player) echo $player->getPlayerName() . "\n";

exit;
```

This outputs

```
player1 
player2
```

see a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/0TJS6)

Comment: This is great, thank you for the extra explanation. So just to clarify one point, where you say a player isn't a team so shouldn't extend the Team class. Would it then make sense to extend Team class with AsianTeam, AfricanTeam etc?

Comment: @BehzadLashkari You are welcome. *"Would it then make sense to extend Team class with AsianTeam, AfricanTeam etc"*.... Yes, `AsianTeam extends Team` makes sense if AsianTeam has all the properties of Team **PLUS** his own extra properties and functions. If AsianTeam desn't need extra properties or functions than the Team, then it should be a vanilla Team.

Answer (score 0):

you could have what you want like this maybe?

```
class Player
{

    private $players = [];

    private $position;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlayers()
    {
        return $this->players;
    }

    /**
     * @param $playerName
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->players[] = $playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }
}



class Team extends Player{

    private $TeamName;

    /**
     * Team constructor.
     * @param $TeamName
     */
    public function __construct($TeamName)
    {
        $this->setTeamName($TeamName);
    }        

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->TeamName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $TeamName
     */
    public function setTeamName($TeamName)
    {
        $this->TeamName = $TeamName;
    }

}



$brazil = new Team('Brazil');
$brazil->setPlayerName('Joe');
$brazil->setPlayerName('Sam');
print_r($brazil->getPlayers());
print_r($brazil->getTeamName());
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
class Team {

    private $TeamName;
    private $Players = [];

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->TeamName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $TeamName
     */
    public function setTeamName($TeamName)
    {
        $this->TeamName = $TeamName;
    }

    public function getPlayers() {
        return $this->Players;
    }

    public function setPlayers($player) {
        $this->Players[] = $player;
    }

}


class Player extends Team
{

    private $playerName;

    private $position;

    private $team;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $playerName
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $position
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
    }

    public function getTeam() {
        return $this->Team;
    }

    public function setTeam(Team $team) {
        $this->team = $team->getTeamName();
        $team->setPlayers($this->playerName);
    }
}

$team = new Team();
$team->setTeamName("Brazil");

$player1 = new Player();
$player1->setPlayerName("Player One");
$player1->setPosition("Attacker");
$player1->setTeam($team);

$player2 = new Player();
$player2->setPlayerName("Player Two");
$player2->setPosition("Keeper");
$player2->setTeam($team);
```

And get Team Players With `$team->getPlayers()`